# Crawling whatsapp web chat list in in correct order with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I want to get all chat `div`s in whatsapp web. I can get them by their class name like this:

```
chats = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_210SC')
```

This would be fine but it only gets first 20 something and gets them what seems like random order.

For example `chats[0].click()` will get me 1st chat and `chat[1].click()` will get me 46th chat.

If I scroll in the middle and execute `driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_210SC')` again I will get different set of chats again in no particular order. It seems like chats are generated dynamically.

Is there a way to get them in order the chats are displayed, for example if my first chat is Mike and second George, `chats[0]` should be Mike and `chats[1]` should be George etc. and what exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatsapp Web is a lazyloaded react app. It's populated with currently 21 elements (for me, not sure if it's depending on screen size?).
Regarding the order of elements, at least right now, it seems to be the top - most recent - entry first, then the following 20 in reverse order, meaning `chat[0] > chat[20] > chat[19] ... chat[1]`

I would try to do the following:
fetch the first 21 elements, scroll to the last element which should be at `chats[1]`, fetch again... until there are no new divs left. Probably you want to keep track of chatters you've fetched already (evaluate the XPath of `//*[@id="pane-side"]//div[@class='_210SC']//div[@class='_3dtfX']//span[@class='_3ko75 _5h6Y_ _3Whw5']` to get their names)

Comment: Its not quite reverse order but something like `chat[0] > chat[20] > chat[19] ... chat[1] chat[4] chat[3] chat[2]`. I tried it multiple times and its always like that for me.  But thank you for giving me a clue. I guess the only solution is to scroll down and get them one by one and track which one you got.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to save the complete contact list. I'm sure there are plenty of other better ways to do it, but this kind of works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

#go to wpp web + time scan qr
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
time.sleep(15)

#click on search field
search_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"copyable-text selectable-text")]')
search_field.click()
time.sleep(3)

#go down to contact list
search_field.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
time.sleep(3)

#appends elements by class + scroll down 
while True:
    contacts = []
    contact_title = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('_3Dr46')
    selected_contact = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@aria-selected="true" and @role="row"]')
    for i in contact_title:
        contacts.append(i.text)
    selected_contact.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    time.sleep(1)
    selected_contact.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    time.sleep(1)
    selected_contact.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

I repeated send_keys 20 times because I was not able to use  ActionChains `(from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains)` because it was too fast and had no time to load the target data.

After, I use the `print(len(contacts))` and `print(contacts)` and the output is  this:

```
16
['num1', 'num2, 'num3','num4'...]
16
['num1', 'num2, 'num4','num5'...]
16
['num2', 'num3, 'num4','num5'...]
```

There it goes until the end of the scroll bar. I'll be posting more updates, now I have to find a way to put all of this in a list with non repetead strings with the value of aprox 200 contacts.

I hope it helps and feel free to show us better ways to do it.